# Could not initialize class sun.security.ec.SunEC Exception in docker

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, ssl

I am running a spring boot application with jasypt in docker. Everything works fine up until I try to add SSL to our application. After setting SSL while startup I get following exception

```
Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ec.SunEC
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:716)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:493)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:469)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:392)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:489)
at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.encryptor.DefaultLazyEncryptor.decrypt(DefaultLazyEncryptor.java:82)
at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultPropertyResolver.resolvePropertyValue(DefaultPropertyResolver.java:35)
at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.resolvePropertyValue(DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.java:41)
at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySource.getProperty(EncryptablePropertySource.java:16)
at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.wrapper.EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper.getProperty(EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper.java:29)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:228)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:88)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:531)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:137)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:133)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:834)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ec.SunEC
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:233)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getIndex(ProviderList.java:263)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProviderConfig(ProviderList.java:247)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:253)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:81)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:101)
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:204)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:689)
... 142 more
```

Another exception trace

```
at sun.security.ec.SunEC.initialize(Native Method)
at sun.security.ec.SunEC.access$000(SunEC.java:49)
at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:61)
at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:58)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ec.SunEC.<clinit>(SunEC.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:233)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:331)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
at org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:54)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:121)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

Docker image is run as devuser. 
If ssl is disabled devuser is able to start the spring boot application with jaspty. However if ssl enable above error.

SSL arguments to server start are

```
-Dsecurity.require-ssl=true -Dserver.ssl.key-store-type=JKS -Dserver.ssl.key-store=file:/app/dev.jks -Dserver.ssl.key-store-password=some_password -Dserver.ssl.key-alias=some_alias
```

I tried to modify entire `$JAVA_HOME` permission to `devuser:devuser` 
`/app` and `dev.jks` file does have devuser ownership and execution mode.

If `USER devuser` is removed from docker then root user is able to start spring boot start with ssl.

I am using open JDK 1.8.0.171

I am missing some permission part of java.security part or may be java.policy part. I am not sure what is that I am missing.

Comment: This `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means that you are missing the library for `sun.security.ec.SunEC`. Make sure it is available in your classpaths or in your libraries folder, or that all of your current libraries "jasypt?" have all their dependencies included.

Comment: It is present in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/ directory.

Comment: Ahh, yes I mislead you. I believe your issue is that you need to add access permission to java.policy using the policytool.exe tool. This is required because you are running your application in a docker/sandbox, and typically a sandboxed application should not have access to it. I am no expert in the topic but here are two very helpful links on how to use the policy tool: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyGuide.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify your nss version in your machines using `rpm -qa  |grep nss-[0-9]` .
Incase your nss version is lower than 3.23, you might need to upgrade it.

[Known Bug with Redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332456)